# Pyinstaller doesn't find crypto. (even in hidden import)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pycrypto

I word with windows 10, python 3.7. (i am also a linux user and to be honest i don't try this with fedora should i try ?)
I use the lastest version of pyinstaller.

When i execute the .exe "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'"

I double check, Crypto is installed.

(I don't need comment like : don't use crypto because it is not safe)

So, since yesterday, l search online.

At the begining, i didn',t know for the hidden import. So i add it to the in the .spec.
But the error still come up.

Then i try to add the hidden import in command and obviously same error.

I read some other post, and i don't really understand the hook.py stuff. In the github projectof pyinstaller, i find a hook folder. And i don't have it on my computer. Should i have them ?

But soemthing weird came up, i have a file in dist\prepare\libcrypto-1_1.dll

And if this file is really about crypto why the .exe don't use it ?

I try with --onefile and --onefolder doesn't change anything.

if you need something, let me know, i will edit the post.

Thank you for your help, and sorry if the question may sound like stupid. 
And sorry for my english ^^

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason, i am a noob

I make a copy of my python direcotry in C:/ and pyinstaller don't find it.^^(because i need it for my IDE)

My bad ^^